# How to get numbers from http://www.example.com/images/business/113.jpg

Tags: c#, regex

Using regex I need to get the numbers between the last "/" and ".jpg" (this actually might be .png, .gif, etc) in this:

> http://www.example.com/images/business/113.jpg

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough using split:

```
var fileName = myUrl.Split('/')[myUrl.Split('/').Length - 1];
var justTheFileName = fileName.Split('.')[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expression are absolute unnecessary here.

Just do:

```
using System.IO;

var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("http://www.example.com/images/business/113.jpg");
```

Take a look at the documentation of the method [GetFileNameWithoutExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx):

> Returns the file name of the specified path string without the extension.

**Edit:**
If you still want to use regex for this purpose, the following one will work:

```
//Both regexes will work here
var pattern = @"/([^/]*)\.jpg"
var pattern2 = @".*/(.*)\.jpg"

var matches = Regex.Matches(pattern, "http://www.example.com/images/business/113.jpg");

if (matches.Count > 0)
    Console.WriteLine(matches[0].Groups[1].Count);
```

**Note:**
I didn't compile the regex. This was a small & fast example.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!! `(?=[\s\S]*?\\.)(?![\s\S]+?/)[0-9]`

PS: The regular expression workbench by microsoft KICKS ASS

Comment: It works... but is uses to much overhead. Check my answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you found a solution matches a single digit in your URL 3 times, but not the entire number. You may want to go with something more "readable" (heh) like this:

```
(?<=\/)\d+(?=\.\w+$)
```

If you're trying to capture the number and use it, throw it into a group:

```
(?<=\/)(\d+)(?=\.\w+$)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regular expression:

`/(?<number>\d+)\.jpg$`

It will capture the number into the named group 'number'. The regular expression works as follows:

1. Search for `/`
2. Capture 1 or more times a digit (0-9) to the named group 'number'
3. Check for .jpg
4. `$` matches the end of the string.

Matching the end makes stuff a lot easier. I don't believe look-ahead or look-behind is necessary.

Comment: Creating regexes can be easier when you read and think from right to left instead of left to right. Especially when you need to match something at the end.

Comment: take in count that `.jpg` doesn't mean `.jpg`. You need to escape the `.`, otherwise you will be matching `ajpg`, `1jpg`, or anything followed by `jpg`.

Comment: @Oscar... wahahaha... you're right. Spur of the moment! Updated the example. Thanks!